# jQuery repeat inside of for loop every second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `for loop` and I am doing path finding. It works! However, when I click on the map, it goes way to fast. How do I slow down what's going on inside the `for loop` to like say... a second between every loop?

```
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {

        var getCoords = new String(result[i]);
        var finalCoords = getCoords.split(",");
        var finalX = finalCoords[0];
        var finalY = finalCoords[1];

        currX = parseInt(x_block);
        currY = parseInt(y_block);

        moving = true;

        realSpawnX = finalX * 32;
        realSpawnY = finalY * 32;

        context.drawImage(playerImg, realSpawnX, realSpawnY, 32, 32);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function loop(i) {
  ++i;

  your code

  if (i < result.length) {setTimeout("loop("+i+")", 1000); }
}
```

at some point start loop:

```
loop(0);
```

**Update:**

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/snies/reSqc/7/)

**Update 2:**

define helper function loop

```
function loop(i, result_length, payload) {
  if (i < result_length) {
    payload(i);
    ++i;          
    setTimeout(function() {loop(i, result_length, payload);} , 2000);
  }
}
```

then call like this on position of the original loop:

```
         loop(0, result.length, function(i) {
                getCoords = new String(result[i]);
                finalCoords = getCoords.split(",");
                finalX = finalCoords[0];
                finalY = finalCoords[1];

                currX = parseInt(x_block);
                currY = parseInt(y_block);

                moving = true;

                realSpawnX = finalX * 32;
                realSpawnY = finalY * 32;
                context.drawImage(playerImg, realSpawnX, realSpawnY, 32, 32);
                console.log("Step taken...");
          });
```

Comment: I did what you said, and it still goes incrediblily fast. The looping part.

Comment: wait, i'll try to make a jsfiddle for you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10820/discussion-between-snies-and-weka)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function funcName(counter, end){
    if(counter < end){
        var getCoords = new String(result[i]);
        var finalCoords = getCoords.split(",");
        var finalX = finalCoords[0];
        var finalY = finalCoords[1];

        currX = parseInt(x_block);
        currY = parseInt(y_block);

        moving = true;

        realSpawnX = finalX * 32;
        realSpawnY = finalY * 32;

        context.drawImage(playerImg, realSpawnX, realSpawnY, 32, 32);

        setTimeout(function(){
            funcName(counter+1, end);
        },1000);
    }
    else{
        movingBlocked=false;
    }
}

//use it like this
movingBlocked = true;
funcName(0, result.length);
while(movingBlocked){
    ;//do nothing
}
```

here's a fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/qcaYh/

**Update**:

Add a global and a busy wait to keep code sync. this has the effect of pausing while waiting for move to finish.

//global
var movingBlocked = false;

Comment: You had some mis-spellings of funct and func... Anwyay, I tried it. It didn't work. There was no looping.

Comment: fixed mis-spellings and removed reference to top frame.

Comment: No, now it doesn't even draw thw player even though it gets the correctX and Y.

Comment: I think @vdbuilder's and my solution both work in solving the timed looping, maybe something else is going wrong. Can you provide a link to a minimal running example of your code? Or try to alter the above jsfiddle example until it shows your problem.